# Using a decorator to apply an inherited method to all child objects of the inherited type

Tags: python, inheritance, meta-programming

I wanted to share this and get some feedback.  My goal was to be able to have an object with methods:

> ```
> class Thing(object):
>     def __init__(self, data=123):
>         self.data = data
>
>     def add_one(self):
>         self.data += 1
>
>     def add_number(self, number):
>         self.data += number
> ```

And then a collection object, `MetaThing` that can hold several `Thing` objects, which inherits from `Thing` like this:

> ```
> class MetaThing(Thing):
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         super(MetaThing, self).__init__()
>
>         self.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>         self.things = []
>         self.setupThings()
>
>     def setupThings(self):
>
>         for i in self.list:
>             thing = Thing(data=i)
>             self.things.append(thing)
> ```

Finally, I want to be able to apply the methods in `Thing` to all the `Thing` instances stored in `MetaThing.things` when those same methods are called on `MetaThing`.

Doing this explicitly creates methods like this:

> ```
>     def add_one(self):
>         for t in self.things:
>             t.add_one()
>
>     def add_number(self, number):
>         for t in self.things:
>             t.add_number(number)
> ```

So I started wondering if this would be a good situation for a decorator, so I wrote one that I think does what I want:

```
def allthings(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        for thing in self.things:
            arglist = list(args)
            arglist[0] = thing
            func(*arglist, **kwargs)

    return new_func
```

So now, the `MetaThing` method can use the `@allthings` decorator to call an inherited method on all child objects without rewriting the for loop every time:

> ```
> class MetaThing(Thing):
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         super(MetaThing, self).__init__()
>
>         self.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>         self.things = []
>         self.setupThings()
>
>     def setupThings(self):
>
>         for i in self.list:
>             thing = Thing(data=i)
>             self.things.append(thing)
>
>     @allthings
>     def add_one(self):
>         self.add_one()
>
>     @allthings
>     def add_number(self, number):
>         self.add_number(number)
> ```

Finally this block verifies that it's working:

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>
>     meta = MetaThing()
>
>     meta.add_one()
>
>     print [t.data for t in meta.things]
>
>     meta.add_number(5)
>
>     print [t.data for t in meta.things]
> ```

Is this a valid approach? Is there a better way to achieve this? Am I crazy for using decorators in this way?

My actual scenario is a `PlottedShape` with lots of methods like plot, delete, update, select, apply_opacity, apply_color, apply_wireframe, etc. and I also have a `PlottedMultiShape` made up of multiple shapes (like a snowman shape made of multiple circles).  If `PlottedMultiShape.select()` is called I want to call `select` on all the child `PlottedShape` objects -- and I'd like this same behavior for all of the other methods as well.  Using a decorator seemed like a good "Don't Repeat Yourself" tactic.

Comment: It is probably a mistake to use an inheritance relationship between `Thing` and `MetaThing` in the first place.  It's a "`MetaThing` contains `Thing`s" relationship, not a "`MetaThing` is a `Thing`" relationship. I can't say for certain what is appropriate, though, since `Thing` is a purely hypothetical example.

Comment: In this case I was trying to say that the same verbs apply to both, that one is simply the plural of the other... like if I wrote Word.capitalize() for some reason, could I get Phrase_of_Words.capitalize() to automatically do `for word in phrase: word.capitalize()`.... and do this also for bold(), underline(), etc.  I see what you mean though... having ThingCollection which owns a list of Things would be more explicit (Composition instead of Inheritance I think?) and could still handle the method proxy/broadcasting behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to use `__getattr__()`.

```
class Wraps(object):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.things = args
  def __getattr__(self, item):
    def each(*args, **kwargs):
      for thing in self.things:
        getattr(thing, item)(*args, **kwargs)
    return each
  def some_real_wraps_method(self):
    print "real method"

class Thing(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def a(self):
    print self.name, "a"
  def b(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print self.name, "b", args, kwargs

w = Wraps(Thing("1"), Thing("2"))
w.a()
w.b()
w.b("arg1", "arg2", named=True)
w.some_real_wraps_method()
```

Running this will output:

```
1 a
2 a
1 b () {}
2 b () {}
1 b ('arg1', 'arg2') {'named': True}
2 b ('arg1', 'arg2') {'named': True}
real method
```

The upside is that you don't have to define an methods in order for them to be proxied. The downside is that it will try to proxy any attribute not defined by `Wraps` (this can be counteracted with a white list).

Comment: yeah I tried to get something similar to work by having a list of methods to wrap and then doing like setattr(self, method, allthings(getattr(self, method))) but it wasn't passing self correctly or something.  Didn't think to just override `__getattr__`.